Java swing scrollpane get all component in horizontally

I am making an e-commerce application. In my dashboard frame I have a search panel one product keeper scroll-panel and one menu panel. I want that all my fetched products can be stored inside product keeper which I can scroll and my search-bar and menu will be at their place but I am getting my all product on one single row and it overflows the screen. I do not know how to fix it.
Here are my code snippets:
public class Deshboard extends JFrame {
    User user;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JScrollPane productkeeper ;
    JButton profileButton = new JButton(" ‍Profile️ ");
JPanel logo = new TestPanel(new Color(118, 226, 229, 255), new Color(114, 197, 191, 255),new Color(114, 197, 191));
    JButton logoutButton = new JButton("  Logout  ");
    JButton settingButton = new JButton("⚙️settings");
    JButton helpButton = new JButton("   Help   ");
    JButton aboutButton = new JButton("  About  ");
 JButton exitButton = new JButton("   Exit ");
    JPanel menuPanel;
    JPanel searchPanel;
    private JPanel productPanel;
    public Deshboard(User current_user) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel( new FlatLightLaf() );
            UIManager.put( "Button.arc", 999 );
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            System.err.println( "Failed to initialize LaF" );
        }
        this.user = current_user;
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        productPanel = new JPanel();
        productPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 10));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         menuPanel = new JPanel();
        menuPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 10));
profileButton.addActionListener(e->{
    new Profile(user);

        }) ;

        menuPanel.add(profileButton);
        menuPanel.add(logoutButton);
        menuPanel.add(settingButton);
        menuPanel.add(helpButton);
        menuPanel.add(aboutButton);

        menuPanel.add(exitButton);

menuPanel.setBackground(new Color(66, 64, 64, 255));
menuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,60));

logo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,50));
        logo.setOpaque(true);
logo.setBackground(Color.cyan);
         searchPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         searchPanel.add(logo,BorderLayout.NORTH);
searchPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,90));
        JTextField searchBar = new IconTextField(new ImageIcon("src/resorce/searchlogo.jpg"));

searchBar.setBorder(  new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(2,10,2,10),new RoundedBorder(8)));

        searchPanel.add(searchBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        searchBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 40));
        searchBar.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        settingButton.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        exitButton.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        logoutButton.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        profileButton.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        helpButton.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        exitButton.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        aboutButton.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        searchButton.setBorder( new CompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,10,5,10),new RoundedBorder(8)));

        searchPanel.add(searchButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        JPanel productPanel = new ImagePanel("src/resorce/shopping-paper-bags-icon-isolated/JEMA GER 1722-04.jpg");

        ArrayList<Product> products = getProducts();
        for (int i = 0 ; i<products.size();i++) {
            ProductCard productCard = new ProductCard(products.get(i));
            productCard.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 5, 10, 5));

            int finalI = i;
            productCard.addToWishlistButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                new Product_add(false).Add_to_Wishlist(user.getName(), products.get(finalI).getName());
            });
            productCard.addToCartButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                new Product_add(false).Add_to_Cart(user.getName(), products.get(finalI).getName());
            });
            Border combination = new CompoundBorder(new RoundedBorder(8),new ShadowBorder(3));

            productCard.setBorder(combination);
productCard.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
       productCard.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    }

                                 @Override
                                 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                                     super.mouseClicked(e);
                                     System.out.println("clicked");
                                 }

                                 public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      productCard.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}
);
            productPanel.add(productCard);
        }
        productPanel.revalidate();
        productPanel.repaint();
productkeeper = new JScrollPane(productPanel);
    productkeeper.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        productkeeper.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);

frame.add(searchPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(menuPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(productkeeper,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        searchButton.addActionListener(e->{
            updateProductPanel(getProducts(searchBar.getText()));
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    private void updateProductPanel(ArrayList<Product> products) {
        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        productPanel = new ImagePanel("src/resorce/shopping-paper-bags-icon-isolated/JEMA GER 1722-04.jpg");

        for (Product product : products) {
            ProductCard productCard = new ProductCard(product);
            productCard.addToWishlistButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                new Product_add(false).Add_to_Wishlist(user.getName(), product.getName());
            });
            productCard.addToCartButton.addActionListener(e->{
                new Product_add(false).Add_to_Cart(user.getName(), product.getName());
            });

            productPanel.add(productCard);
        }
        frame.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(productPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }


You are saying that there is no horizontal scrollbar on the JScrollPane, however you set the horizontal scrollbar policy to NEVER. Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Do you want your products on one row?  Or do you want them to be wrapped, so they take up as many rows as are needed to display them without needing a horizontal scrollbar?

i fianally got solution i want my product to be wreped i add my all products in pne jpanal and add that jpanal in to my scrollpanal and i dynamicaly set prefered size of my jpanal according to no. of product by calculating hight of one product and do some calculation . and it works fine

frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
Dimension newSize = new Dimension(800 , products.size()*90);
productPanel.setPreferredSize(newSize);
productPanel.revalidate();
}
});

 frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        Dimension newSize = new Dimension(800 , products.size()*90);
        productPanel.setPreferredSize(newSize);
           productPanel.revalidate();
            }
        });

i set my scrollpanal,s prefered size according to fathed product and it works fine
